# How to instantiate `PostgreSQLQuery` in Querydsl?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, querydsl

I need to use `PostgreSQLQuery` in order to perform `distinctOn()` on some queries.

Before, when I did not need `distinctOn()`, I was using JPA queries like this:

```
QUser qUser = QUser.user;
JPAQueryFactory queryFactory = new JPAQueryFactory(entityManager);
JPAQuery<User> query = queryFactory.selectFrom(qUser)
   ...
;
```

where `entityManager` is wired in my class with `@PersistenceContext`:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

However, `PostgreSQLQuery` takes a connection as input parameter instead of an entity manager. How can I instantiate a `PostgreSQLQuery` query object?